# Unexpected return value of Numpy.sum() in my local Jupyter

Tags: python, numpy, sum

When running the following code
when `N = 100000` I get `-1724114088`

Otherwise, I get the right answer when running it in web python editor.

Does my Jupter have any setting error?

```
def sq(N):
    return np.sum(np.arange(N)**2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def sq(N):
    return np.sum(np.arange(N, dtype = np.int64)**2)
```

The numbers in your example are too large for the `np.int32` data type, which numpy uses by default. If you use `np.int64` you can go up to `N = 10000000`

Comment: The default `dtype` seems to depend on the system, e.g. it already uses `int64` on mine. However, even when explicitly setting `dtype` as `int32`, I get a different sum than what OP claims to get.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I wasn't aware of that.
If you choose `N = 1000` you will get OPs output, he just typed one additional 0 by mistake I guess

Comment: Hm, tried different values of N and different dtypes, but never got OP's value. Still, that's probably the right solution to the problem.